# Merge identical records with batch apex, turn not identical fields in said records into a multipicklist

Tags: apex, batch, query, duplicate-management, merge-field

I'm a novice and this is my first post here so I apologize if im doing this wrong

I have a requirement where i need to use batch apex to: Merge records with the identical fields "Name" and "SObjectCode" down to a single record

But here is the catch: that SObject have a field called "ActiveOffice" (a multi-picklist)

When I merge the identical records I need every field to merge but I **need to combine "ActiveOffice" fields (which are not identical) into a multi-picklist value.

The remaining problem: How do I query those dupes and merge them, send the different fields to another list to then update it in the surviving record?

Any guidance to build this apex batch will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Is your question about writing the batch class, or is it about merging the multipicklist values from two records into the surviving (post-merge) record? If you have a list of strings, your example code would be how you set the final result into the multipicklist field. Some additional information about where, precisely, you're stuck would help.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome!
I don't know how to structure the batch class to query all those duplicates and insert them in different lists (so i can then merge them)
And also im kinda lost in the merging itself with batch classes. How do I get the field values of all the objects that I have in said list?
I kinda know how to do each thing, but I can't seem to find a way to build the batch class to do all of this, trailhead and salesforce dev forum doesn't have much stuff about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-faceted question (the stackexchange format highly encourages narrow questions), but let's see if I can keep things at a reasonable length.

#### Using batch Apex

The benefit of batch Apex is that it allows you to break up a big dataset (or something that just takes a lot of processing) into more manageable chunks. Each chunk (of 200 records by default) that the query locator (or iterator) returned by the `start()` method gets its own set of governor limits to play with.

I don't have that much experience with batch Apex, but my gut feeling is that you probably don't want to include the records that will be deleted as part of the merge in the result of the `start()` method. So your goal here is to have your query locator only return the records that you intend to be the survivors of the merge.

If you can mark the records you want to survive prior to scheduling the batch class for execution, that'd make your batch class simpler. Otherwise, you may want to create a helper class (or a helper method) to do that processing for you.

#### How to find duplicates

When you have multiple fields that you're looking at filtering against, SOQL alone is insufficient.

The typical approach is to use a loop to gather the data you'll use in the WHERE clause into a list, and then include that in your query like so

```
List<String> myAccountNames = new List<String>();
for(Account acct :accountList){
    myAccountNames.add(acct.Name);
}

for(Account acct :[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name IN :myAccountNames]){
    // Do some work
}
```

but when you try to filter on more than just one list (as you would be doing with Name and SObject code), SOQL doesn't filter on list1[0] and list2[0], it would filter on every possible combination of list1 and list2 (i.e. the cartesian product of the two lists)

One common way around that is to use a formula field to combine the two (or however many) fields. Something simple like `Name + ':' + SObjectCode` would work. The important part is that you're condensing things into a single field. When you have a single field, SOQL can handle things in the way you intend.

This would be placed in the `execute()` method of your batch class, something like

```
// assuming "scope" is the name of one of the arguments to the execute() method...

// Using a List<Account> as the map value type to be able to hold all of the accounts
//   that duplicate our formula field
Map<String, List<Account>> nameAndCodeToAccounts = new Map<String, List<Account>>();

// Gather the data for our duplicates query
List<String> nameAndCodeList = new List<String>();
for(Account acct :scope){
    nameAndCodeList.add(acct.Combined_Formula_Field__c);
}

for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, Name, Code__c FROM Account WHERE Combined_Formula_Field__c IN :nameAndCodeList]){
    String nameAndCode = acct.Combined_Formula_Field__c;

    // This is a generally nice way to populate maps
    // Add the key to the map if it doesn't exist, and then we are guaranteed
    //   to have something usable outside of the IF
    // No need for an ELSE block, so it saves some typing
    if(!nameAndCodeToAccounts.containsKey(nameAndCode)){
        nameAndCodeToAccounts.put(nameAndCode, new List<Account>());
    }

    nameAndCodeToAccounts.get(nameAndCode).add(acct);
}

// Now nameAndCodeToAccounts contains all of the unique values of the formula field
//   for the records provided in the "scope"
// If the size of the list stored by any given key is more than 1, then you have duplicates
```

#### Combining multipicklist values

My first approach would be to use a `Set<String>`. Sets will never contain duplicate data, which is nice if you want to avoid situations where you try to store `item1;item1;item2;item2;item2;item3` in a multipicklist field (though to be truthful, I think Salesforce can handle such a situation just fine for multipciklists).

Multipicklists are stored as semicolon-delimited strings, so combining them can simply be a matter of splitting the string, adding everything to a collection, and then joining the string back together.

```
for(List<Account> acctsForKeyValue :nameAndCodeToAccounts.values()){
    Set<String> uniqueValues = new Set<String>();

    for(Account acct :acctsForKeyValue){
        uniqueValues.addAll(acct.MultiPicklist_Field__c.split(';'));
    }

    // String.join() needs a list, not a set
    // Thankfully, the List class has a constructor that can take a Set
    String combinedPicklistValue = String.join(new List<String>(uniqueValues), ';');
}
```

Comment: note that merge is not a bulkified DML verb so if included in a batch execute(), you have to do them in a loop (DML in a for loop !) and limit scope size to something considerably less than 200

Comment: Derek, I can't believe that you took the time to explain this so clearly. Thank you so much :')